# Find the sum of the roots given no multiple roots.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Find the sum of the roots, real and non-real, of the equation $$ x^{2001} + \left( \frac{1}{2} - x \right)^{2001} = 0  $$ given that there are  no multiple roots.

I am in a weird situation here.

$$x^{2001} = -\left( \frac{1}{2} - x \right)^{2001}$$

$$x = -\frac{1}{2} + x$$

Then I get $0 = -\frac{1}{2}$ which I know is not true.

So all roots have to be complex roots. 
By vieta's formulas:

$$\sum _{k=1}^{n} r_k = -\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$

But that cant be of help here. The leading coefficient is $Cx^{2000}$.

**Hints please, no complete answers, thank you!**

Comment: well can't you use [Newton's binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to compute the leading coefficients?

Comment: Ah jesus. $$(1/2 - x)^{2001} = \sum_{k=0}^{2001} \binom{2001}{k} (1/2)^k (-x)^{2001 - k}$$ the $k's$ I am after are: $k = \{1, 2\}$. Hence, $a_n = 2001(1/2)$ and $a_{n-1} = 2001000 (1/4) = 500250$. $\sum r_k = \frac{1000500}{2001} =  500$$?

Comment: You're on the good track :). Pay attention to the fact that $a_n = 2001\cdot (1/2)+\color{red}{1}$ (since you are dealing with $\color{red}{x^{2001}}+(1/2-x)^{2001}$) Moreover note that your sum starts at $0$ (and so $(1/2)^0 = 1$) and don't forget the $\color{blue}{-}$ in $(\color{blue}{-}x)^{2001-k}=\color{blue}{(-1)^{2001-k}}x^{2001-k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{2001} + (\frac{1}{2} - x)^{2001} = 0 \implies x^{2001} + \sum_0 ^{2001} \binom{2001}{k} (\frac{1}{2})^{2001 - k} (-x)^k = 0$... What does Vieta's formula say at this point?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $(z^a)^{\frac{1}{a}}\neq z$ In general. There are exactly $n$ $n^{th}$ roots of a number if we allow complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a difference of two powers formula on $x^{2001} - (x - 1/2)^{2001}$, then using Vieta's formulae.